# Configuring ObjectDataSource: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, objectdatasource, configure

In my project in Visual Studio 2010, I'm trying to add an Object Data Source which points to one to my business services, and to bind the datasource to a datagrid (or datalist, or whatever).

The problem is, after adding the ObjectDataSource from the toolbox, when I hit the "Configure Data Source" link to open the configuration wizard I get this error:

> Error invoking Configure Data Source - Exception has been thrown by
>   the target of an invocation

This only happens in my project (i.e. if I create a blank project, ObjectDataSource configuration works properly).

Searching similar questions here in stackoverflow and on the internet I've read that this error is often related to a missing assembly. In fact, my project references several .dlls, and after checking time and again I just can't see what is missing. I also tried enhabling logging on Visual Studio, but it doesn't log anithing related to that error.

So: is there a way to get a more exhaustive error message from Visual Studio? Perhaps accessing the "inner exception" that fired the error, like you do when debugging your code?

And by the way: is there a way to configure "manually" ObjectDataSources without using the wizard?